# how to set InputType to InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER in Android Version 7.0 (nougat) and above

Tags: android, keyboard, android-7.0-nougat

I have created Custom Edittext in which i set the InputType as `this.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);` but the problem is it working perfectly on below 7.0(nougat) but above 7.0 it show me alphanumeric keyboard.

one another weird thing happen is  when I touch the EditText, I quickly get the soft numerical keyboard, but in less than a second it automatically changes to regular soft keyboard showing all letters. also when keyboard is open, than ill press back button, than keyboard close, but when i re-enter in Edittext. keyboard is not open until i click on onther edittext then current edittext

Is this issue in Nougat or I am doing something wrong

For information i have used code to setSoftInputMode to ADJUST PAN

```
setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN
                    |WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

and to set Numeric keypad use  `this.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);`

**Edited -** 
             when i remove -

```
setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN
                        |WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

from activity every thing work fine( number keypad open at number edittext , alphanumerical keypad open at alphanumerical edittext ) except the content not goes up-direction means keypad hide edittext(because ignorance of this property SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)

**Help appreciated thanks**

Comment: Android expert are u there ?????????

Comment: `I have created Custom Edittext` You probably shouldn't do that. EditText code is above both your and my pay grade. `in which i set the InputType as [...]` You probably didn't do just that. It's hard to see what's wrong if you don't share full code of this custom EditText. Post the whole class.

Comment: @Eugen Pechanec  !! issue is not in "custom EditText " if it is CustomeEdittext then Alphanumeric keypad should open below nougat but it open Number keypad .... also when i remove setSoftInputMode =AdjustPan property than it show me number keypad which is perfect but then it hide my edittext behind keypad  :(

Comment: in short "setSoftInputMode" this property change the state of edittext from numerical to alphanumerical

Comment: @sushantgosavi Nobody is clairvoyant. If you need help publish(for example, on github) your project as is(if it possible , of course), link it here and someone helps you.

Comment: @ Dima Kozhevin  ...It is not possible to share my all code coz this is about banking application ...........But i dont thing so the problem in other code coz it work perfect on below 7

Comment: Got some clue !! I have testing this on 4 to 5 device of 7 OS (nougat) and in which 2 device having problem 3 device has no issue ........still confused about this

Comment: My tester having same device that has issue ...:( :(

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER) on devices 7+ and didn't see the behaviour that you described.  Looking for another thread, runnable or any callback which changing InputType of your EditText after opening or simultaneously.

Comment: created new app with number input type and run on nougat device it work fine (number keypad open) but in my app not work, in my app i didn't understand why it not only work on and above nougat only ..........and twest is when i remove softinputmode= adjustPan property it work but keyboard hide edittext ....:(

Comment: in short "setSoftInputMode" this property change the state of edittext from numerical to alphanumerical –

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `softInputMode` in your `Manifest` file, it might give you your desired behavior.

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

Comment: I have already added that line in Manifest  file my one is - android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden"